# Hyperlink is lost using <a> tag in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and in my view, I am trying to add "Edit | Delete" functionality within a table. I am getting a hyperlink for my edit, but I don't get any hyperlink for delete.

Here is my markup in the view:

```
<td id="pagefunc">
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.POC_Id }) |
    <a data-record-id="@item.POC_Id" class="js-delete delete">Delete</a>
</td>
```

Here is the screen shot of the section, on which edit gives me a hyperlink but delete does not:

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and why I am not getting a hyperlink on hovering over the delete link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<td id="pagefunc">
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.POC_Id }) |
     <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.POC_Id })" class="js-delete delete">
              <span>Delete</span>
     </a>    
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that resolved my issue, much appreciated.! But still not clear what made it lose the hyperlink for the <a> tag in the first place...